# Set up SQL Database table in Delphi with TDBGrid (Unidirectional error)

Tags: delphi, tdbgrid

How can i set the whole table of a database to show in my delphi form? Using TDBGrid i presume; but when I configure the data source (connected to a query) I receive an error message about it being Unidirectional. I've heard about a Clientdataset but that didnt seem to work. Could i have some clear instructions on how to do this please? Thank you in advance, Toby.

Comment: Seriously, you can't do a Google search on *tclientdataset example* and locate one? I just did, and got 10 pages of results, with the entire first page full of step by step tutorials.

Comment: I'm sorry but that really doenst help me. I want a single database table, one grid, and im doing it graphically so im not sure the relevance of the first link you mention, also there is no step by step... I just need a really basic explanation of wich components i need to insert to display query results in a grid. Sorry for any confusion

Comment: If you want to use TDBGrid or any of the multirecord data aware controls, the query cannot be Unidirectional.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how can I make it not unidirectional? Sorry I really am a beginner, not sure what that means. Thanks again

Comment: What is the query component you are using?

Comment: I believe that is part of dbExpress. Those components were designed to be Unidirectional only  You will have to connect it to a TDataSetProvider and TClientDataSet or change your query component.  You could use TADODataSet, its default CursorType will allow you to use TDBGrid.

Comment: How do i connect it to datasetprovider and clientdataset? Not sure how clientdataset relates to datasetprovider and then dbgrid? Thanks

Comment: Set the DataSet property of TDataSetProvider to the SQLQuery.  Set the ProviderName property of the TClientDataSet to the DataSetProvider.  Set the DataSet Property of your TDataSource to the ClientDataset.  When the ClientDataset is opened, it will contain the data from your SQLQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say you are using TSQLQuery.  This is one of the dbExpress components which are designed to be Unidirectional only (except the TSimpleDataSet).  You either have to connect the TSQLQuery to a TDataSetProvider and TClientDataSet or change your query component to one that will buffer the data locally.

To use TDataSetProvider and TClientDataSet:

- Set the DataSet property of TDataSetProvider to the SQLQuery.
- Set the ProviderName property of the TClientDataSet to the DataSetProvider.
- When the ClientDataset is opened, it will contain the data from your SQLQuery.

Set the DataSet Property of your TDataSource to the ClientDataset so the data can be displayed in your DBGrid.

Since you appear to be new to using databases with Delphi, I would recommend you use a different query component, because using the TDataSetProvider and TClientDataSet can be complicated.  I suggest

- TSimpleDatSet in dbExpress,
- TADOQUery or TADODataset in dbGo,
- TQuery in BDE (not recommended),
- TFDQuery in FireDAC, or
- other third party query components.

Comment: Thank you, I'm not receiving any errors now, so that is good. Unfortunately there is no data in the grid which currently has only one cell. How can I populate the grid? I've tested the SQL query and that is bringing up results. Thanks for your help up to now! Toby

Comment: You say when the clientDataset is opened... what do you mean? Thanks

Comment: I'm so sorry haha me being stupid. ClientDataSet.Open lol. Thanks a lot it is working :))))) Happy now. Thanks!